# Wifi not connecting immediately after sleep

Tags: wireless

Yet another ubuntu/wifi question!

I have a problem with my wifi taking between 10 and 30 seconds to connect on my home network.

After sleep, the wifi isn't connected but I can see the list of available networks (excluding my wifi). It sometimes takes up to 30 seconds for my network to appear in the list, at which point it reconnects immediately. Sometimes I have to disable/reenable airplane mode for it to find my wifi. I observe the same problem when enable then disable airplane mode on my pc.

This only seems to happen on my home network, at work/university it will connect immediately. My wifi network has many other wifi networks around and the bandwidth is kind of saturated which doesn't help.

The thing is my phone seems to manage to connect to my wifi immediately, everytime. So I'm wondering if there is a setting I could change (something like a wifi refresh I'm guessing) which I could adjust to make ubuntu see the wifi faster.

Thanks for your help!

PS: I'm running Ubuntu 19.04 but I have observed this problem before

Answer (score 2):

This can sometimes happen as a result of wireless power saving mode being set to enabled as this is the default setting.

---

You can disable the wireless adapter power saving mode as follows:

- Run the following command in the terminal:

`sudo nano /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf`

- An editor will open. Please find:

`wifi.powersave = 3`

and change it to:

`wifi.powersave = 2`

- Save and exit by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> then press <kbd>Y</kbd> then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
- Reboot your system for the change to take effect.

---

> **`wifi.powersave` modes explained:**
>
> `wifi.powersave = 3` means enable wireless adapter power saving
>
> `wifi.powersave = 2` means disable wireless adapter power saving

Comment: Thanks this seems to be a bit better! Unfortunately it still takes some time to connect so I'm still hoping someone might come up with another solution :)

Comment: @chewy-unicorn You are most welcome. I am glad it helped.